# Array in the parameter when creating PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Can I use a few lines in the parameter
Example

```
SELECT id, city_id FROM an_objects WHERE city_id IN (:arrCity)
```

**(:arrCity) (1,2,3,4,5,6)**
But now I have done like this

```
SELECT id, city_id FROM an_objects WHERE city_id IN (:1p, :2p, :3p, ...... :100p)
```

And it's very bad

Comment: You can construct the parameter list in the prepared statement dynamically, using a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

private function PDOBindArray(&$poStatement, &$paArray){ 
    foreach ($paArray as $k=>$v) {
        @$poStatement->bindValue($k, $v[0], $v[1]);
    }      
}

// the array structure should now look something like this

$inputArray = array(
    ':arrcity' => array($email, PDO::PARAM_STR), 
    ':another_variable' => array($pass, PDO::PARAM_INT)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And how in that case to be a query?

```
WHERE city_id IN (:1p, :2p, :3p, ...... :100p)
```

In the query 100 parameters
In this method, for example, we have only 5 parameters

```
private function PDOBindArray(&$poStatement, &$paArray){ 
    foreach ($paArray as $k=>$v) {
        @$poStatement->bindValue($k, $v[0], $v[1]);
    }      
}
```